# Ending infinite loop for a bot

Tags: python, loops, infinite

I have created a chat bot for **Twitch IRC**, I can connect and create commands etc etc, however I cannot use keyboard-interrupt in the command prompt. I suspect it is because it's stuck in this infinite loop, and I don't know how to fix this? I am new to programming btw!

Here is the code I have in my `Run.py`, `openSocket()` is defined in another file, basically connection to the server. `s = socket.socket.`
First part in the while-loop basically just reads the server messages, I think it's pretty straight forward for you guys!

```
s = openSocket()
joinRoom(s)
readbuffer = ""

while True:
        readbuffer = readbuffer + s.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")
        temp = str.split(readbuffer, "\n")
        readbuffer = temp.pop()

        for line in temp:
            if "PING" in line:
                s.send("PONG :tmi.twitch.tv\r\n".encode("utf-8"))
                print("---SENT PONG---")
            printMessage(getUser, getMessage, line)
            message = getMessage(line)

            for key in commands:
                command = key
                if command in message:
                    sendMessage(s, commands[command])
```

((Edit: I also have this problem where the connection to the server seems to time out for whatever reason. I managed to get it keep connection with ping/pong for about 40-45min, but then it disconnected again.

EDIT:

Sorry the original post was super messy. I have created this pastebin with the least amount of code I could use to recreate the problem.
If the IRC chat is inactive it will disconnect, and I can't get it to send 2 pings in a row without any messages in between, not sure if that's because it disconnects before the 2nd ping or because of the 2nd ping.

On at least one occasion it has disconnected even before I got the first ping from the server.

Pastebin: pastebin.com/sXUW50sS

Comment: Do you use multithreading, perhaps implicitly in `joinRoom`? Only the main thread can be killed by signals.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/b3h2Y9BE here you can see all of the functions that I have used to connect to the server!

Comment: That is not particularly helpful. Please try to create a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Are you sure your loop is actually advancing? If your socket does not have enough data, asking it for a fixed size (`s.recv(1024)`) will *block*. That's a blocking system call, which you *cannot* abort from inside python. It would also explain your timeout.

Comment: I'm actually not quite sure about anything, if it's advancing or how to fix this potential problem with (s.recv(1024)). I am such a novice and this whole section of the bot was just something I wanted to get past so I could practice easier things.

I could try to give you a more useful link, but I'm very unsure what to include in it. I can just try to make one including all of the parts that are relevant to the connection, I guess..

Comment: http://pastebin.com/sXUW50sS

Sorry for the late response, this is the least amount of code I can have to recreate the problem. The bot keeps disconnecting even if it's sending a PONG, altough this only happens if the chat is inactive, if people are actively chatting it seems to be fine. I also cannot easily get out of the bot in the command prompt, have to close it all down as it's stuck in the loop.

Comment: Do you see any of those debug `print` statements before the issue occurs? I'm really betting on `s.recv` blocking because there is no data. If you want do dig through this, have a look at the [python socket HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sockets.html). It has a section on how message length can lead to your situation and how to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Part of code that you posted doesn't have much to do with problem you described.

This is a guess (although an educated one). In you socket connection you are probably using `try: except:` and using `Pokemon` approach (gotta catch 'em all)

Thing here would be to find a line where you are doing something like this:

```
except:
    pass
```

and change it to:

```
except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
    raise
except:
    pass
```

Obviously I'm not trying to say here that your porgram should catch all exceptions and just pass like if nothing happened. Main point is that you are probably already doing that (for i-have-no-idea-why reasons) and you should have special treatment for system errors.

Comment: `KeyboardInterrupt` doesn't extend `Exception` so `except Exception: pass` should still catch everything but let Ctrl-C rise.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/b3h2Y9BE here you can see my whole INIT file where the openSocket() function is defined. As I said I'm kinda new and I followed some guy on youtube on doing this part, as it is quite a bit above my level.